# How do I edit the Mapped Folder contents in a package

Tags: 2010, solution-package

I have some files that somehow got included in a Mapped Folder in a package. I deleted the files because they are not necessary but I can't figure out how to tell the package to stop including them. Where do I edit the list of files to include from the mapped folder?
[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goto visual studio, within solution explorer look for the folders that contain a green circle in the bottom right corner of the folder... that is a mapped folder, go into the folder + folders to find the files that you dont want and just remove them, right click the file that you dont want and click delete!

where are you deleting the files from? 14hive? where in 14hive if you are?